# Make A Receipt From?

Tags: idioms

If I purchased something a merchant, then, according to members of this forum, I could write this:

> I *made a purchase* ***from*** the merchant.

as standard English, with the preposition "*from*" denoting that merchant is the source of the stuff purchased.

Suppose I received something from somebody.  Using the pattern "*make a purchase from*" as inspiration, could I write the following:

> I *made a receipt* ***from*** the merchant.

as standard English?

Comment: No, *make a receipt* is not English.

Comment: One way to think about it is: the buyer **makes** a purchase from and **gets** a receipt from the merchant; the merchant **makes** a receipt and **gives** it to the buyer

Answer (score 2):

We don't say "make a receipt" in the sense that you're using it.

The word "receipt" can mean "the act of receiving", or it can refer to a piece of paper that describes a transaction.

If I heard someone say "I made a receipt", I would normally interpret that to mean that he produced a piece of paper describing a transaction. Like, "You key the item ordered, the price, and other relevant information into the computer, and then it makes a receipt." In that case you wouldn't "make a receipt from a merchant". You can make a receipt "from the information about the transaction". You can make a receipt "for a merchant". But to "make a receipt from a merchant", well, the only sense I can make of that is that you printed the receipt on the merchant's face or some such.

You are probably thinking of "receipt" in the sense of receiving something, like "You must acknowledge receipt of the merchandise." In that case you don't "make a receipt". You can receive something, as in, "I received my order from the merchant". That would be the normal way to say it, I think. You could say, "I accepted receipt" or some such phrasing, but few fluent speakers would say that.

Comment: But in "*make a purchase* ***from***", it involves receiving merchandise from a seller, just as "*make a receipt* ***from***" involves receiving something from the giver.

Comment: Yes, but the words just aren't used the same. We simply do not say, "make a receipt". Whether or not this makes sense to your intuition, that's just not a phrase that native English speakers use.

Comment: @Jay +1 From my experience, the closest a native might say is "Could you make **out** a receipt for me?" but usually the request would be "Could I have a receipt for this?"

Comment: @peter Yes. I was struggling to find a context where we would say "make a receipt", not trying to say this is a common thing to say. I probably wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Would you please **make a receipt** out of papyrus, I don't like wood pulp

Answer (score 1):

> RECEIPT
>
> noun
>
> 1.the action of receiving something or the fact of its being received: *"I would be grateful if you would acknowledge receipt of this letter"*

A purchase is something *you make*. A receipt is something *you receive*. Think of it as a "Proof Of Purchase."

If you want to put *your purchase* and *your receipt* in the same sentence just remember that the tense of the verbs should be similar.

> Whenever I make a purchase from my favorite merchant, she always takes
>   a moment to write, "Thank you," on the receipt before handing it to me.